# How to view/select a specific value in a joined table?

Tags: php, eloquent

hi i wanna know how can i get a specific value from joined table.

here's my code

```
    $bank_detail = $this->db->table('sys_bank_details')->where('bank_name', $bank)->first();

    $bank_detail_arr = array(
        'account_type' => $bank_detail->account_type,
        'bank_name' => $bank_detail->bank_name,
        'account_name' => $bank_detail->account_name,
        'account_number' => $bank_detail->account_number,
    );
```

in the code above i can get specific data, because it only has one table only

but how can i get if i joined tables? here's my code

```
    // Total sale and Transaction Made
    $total_sales = $this->db->table('order_payment')
    ->select(DB::raw('*, sum(order_payment.amount) as total_amount, order_header.*, count(order_header.order_type_id) as total_transaction'))
    ->leftjoin('order_header', 'order_header.order_id', '=', 'order_payment.order_id')
    ->where(DB::raw('Date(reference_date)'), $sales_date)
    ->where('order_header.order_type_id', '2')
    ->where('order_header.store_id', $manager->store_id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: what value do you want to get?

Comment: i dunno how to get the value

Comment: ```$total_sales->total_amount``` and so on